# Aligning difficulties

Tags: html

See image attached, I need each box in the bottom left to be right next to the "NO IMAGE" images, I've tried all sorts of aligning but can't seem to figure it out :S is there an easy way of doing this that I'm missing out on?

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
<?php
include("header.php");
include("connect.php");

$getchamps = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM champions ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10");

?>

<style type="text/css">
TD{font-family: Arial; font-size: 8pt;}

</style>

<?php

while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($getchamps)){
$name = $r['name'];

    $img = '<img src="images/noimage.gif" />';

?>

<?php echo "<center>",$img,"</center><br>"; ?>

  <table BORDERCOLOR="grey" align="center" width="200" height="310">
<tr>
<td><b><font style="font-size: 8pt; color:#6699CC;">Name:</font></b></td>
<td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
}
?>


<?php
include("footer.php");
?>
```

"$img" is the "NO IMAGE" and the table is what displays the boxes.

IGNORE PREVIOUS!!

Sorry, here's a better pic:
[image]

VERY bad img of what I want it to look like..

[image]

UPDATE

[image]

Comment: Your markup is made up almost entirely of obsolete or deprecated tags and improper usage of other tags. CENTER is deprecated, FONT is obsolete, and you're using a table for non-tabular display. Read up on CSS positioning (ex: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

Comment: @BrianStephens Thanks I'm looking at it now, I've been using these tags for hundreds of lines of code lol Which one is specific to this problem? I've tried a few with no luck so far

Comment: It's difficult to see how you want the output (the box "right next to the image"). Can you show a mockup of the intended layout?

Comment: We appreciate the effort of posting images but it is still unclear what is the position desired for each element. Is the 'No-image' the actual image? An empty DIV ? or the table

Comment: @AwRak The NO  IMAGE is an actual image, the table is the "NAME", sorry. I will be putting multiple rows in the table :)

Comment: @Ben See comment below. You just need to switch the float position and adjust the width to suit your needs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is some float positioning with CSS. I put an example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o8tsjdwt/2/).

**EDIT:** I updated this solution and the fiddle to add spacing between "champs".

Here's the markup:

```
<div class="champ">
    <img class="noimage" src="" alt="no image" />
    <div class="info">
        <div class="namelabel">Name:</div>
        <div class="name">Sample Name 1</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="champ">
    <img class="noimage" src="" alt="no image" />
    <div class="info">
        <div class="namelabel">Name:</div>
        <div class="name">Sample Name 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.champ {
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0 auto 8px auto;
    width: 358px;
}
.noimage {
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.info {
    float: left;
    height: 60px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font: 8pt Arial;
    padding: 40px 0 0 4px;
}
.namelabel {
    float: left;
    color: #6699CC;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
```

Comment: That works great for the alignment :) EDIT sorry I just need them to be aligned in the center now but I'ma look it up, can't have everything done for me

Comment: `margin-left: 26%;` was what I added to `.champ` div to emulate a central alignment!

Comment: Here's the best way to center-align them: add "auto" margin left and right, along with a specific width (so it's not the default 100%). I'll update the answer and fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You can try wrapping your table in a DIV and your image as well and float each DIV

```
#mainWrapper{
   position:relative;
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
    }

table{ 
 display:block;
    }

#tableWrapper{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    }

#imageWrapper{
    float:right;
    width:50%;
    }

<div id="mainWrapper">
    <div id="tableWrapper">
        <table>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>row</td>
                <td>row</td>
                <td>row</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row</td>
                <td>row</td>
                <td>row</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row</td>
                <td>row</td>
                <td>row</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row</td>
                <td>row</td>
                <td>row</td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>

    <div id="imageWrapper">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISZpH.png" alt=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This has really helped me to understand CSS and divs a lot more as I barely use them. But it doesn't work, doe the image not need to be in the "mainwrapper"?

Comment: If you want to align both the table and Image then Yes. Include them within the same container, then wrap your table with a DIV and your image as well. Now for each wrapper give it a width and height then a float position.

Comment: Sorry I fixed the CSS these are Ids (#) not classes, replace the dot with a hash if you copied the code earlier

Comment: I want them to be next to eachother (as shown in poorly drawn picture added recently).  This code gets them on the same line but the floats put them on the other side of the page to eachother

Comment: if you want the image on the left then change the float position in #imageWrapper{ float:left; } intead of float:right and in #tableWrapper{float:right} , float:right means the element will be on the right and vice versa.. Then if you want the table to occupy less space change its width to a less percentage and increase the image to a higher

Comment: thanks for your help but it's really not working, the table is more 'further down' than the image, it's impossible for me to get them aligned how I want due to width being either too much or not enough lol And even then they both overlap my header/footer :) I'll just search the net and if I find an article that solves it I'll post it as a reply